# How to pass a variable value into json file using java

Tags: java, json

I have a variable value that I want to pass into my json file for one of the entity.

I am using rest assured and java for this. I have a value:

```
int ageValue = 20;
```

and my json file looks like this:

```
{

"firstName":"test",

"age":"${ageValue}"

}
```

I want to pass `ageValue` into my json file using java.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify: how does your entity look like, how do you serialize it to JSON, what current code you're executing.

Answer (score 0):

The libraries Jackson and Google Gson both enable this very easily, and both are on Maven Central so can be included easily in any Maven/Gradle projects. I am more familiar with Jackson so I will use it for an example below:

```
public class Person {
    private int ageValue;
    private String firstName;

    // getters and setters - these are essential for most libraries to function
}
```

And then, to convert to Json:

```
Person person = ... // generate person
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(person);
```

And to convert back:

```
String json = ...  // from above
Person person = new ObjectMapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create JsonObject like the following, if you don't want to use any additional library-

```
    String firstName = "test";
    int ageValue = 20;
    JSONObject userObject = new JSONObject();
    userObject.put("firstName", firstName);
    userObject.put("age", ageValue);
```